# Can you use both @XmlElement and @JsonProperty together inside a POJO class

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I have a json payload and an xml payload, and I want to map both of the payloads into one POJO class. One endpoint returns a json and the other a xml. Can i combine both into one pojo class.

```
{
  "house": 'big',
  "has-large-house": "yes"
}

<completed-houses>
.....
</completed-houses>
```

```
public PayloadResponse(
        @JsonProperty("house") final String house,
        @JsonProperty("has-large-house") final String hasLargeHouseList,
        @XmlElement(name="completed-houses") final String completeHouses) {
    this.house = house;
    this.hasLargeHouseList = hasLargeHouseList;
    this.completeHouses = completeHouses;
}
```

and then getters and setter for these properties.

Comment: *That* is not a valid JSON file, and it is not a valid XML file, so there are no parsers that would accept that, which means that your question about how to do it in Java, is moot.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. It's not a valid JSON. It's not a valid XML.

Comment: Your updated question doesn't make any sense either. The JSON and the XML don't even contain the same values (e.g. there are no values in the XML), so why do you expect them to map into a single class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!  You can combine Jackson and JAXB annotations in the same POJO, using the [Jackson module for JAXB annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) so that Jackson can understand JAXB annotations, and [`jackson-dataformat-xml`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) for serializing to XML.

Here is an example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PayloadResponse {
    private String house;

    @JsonProperty("has-large-house")
    private boolean largeHouse;

    @XmlElement(name = "completed-houses")
    private String completedHouses;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        xmlMapper.registerModule(module);

        PayloadResponse response = new PayloadResponse();
        response.setHouse("The White House");
        response.setLargeHouse(true);
        response.setCompletedHouses("1600 Pennsylvania Ave.");

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        // Serialize value as XML.
        xmlMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, response);
        System.out.println("XML=" + stringWriter);

        // Serialize value as JSON.
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        stringWriter.getBuffer().setLength(0);
        jsonMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, response);
        System.out.println("JSON=" + stringWriter);
    }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
XML=<PayloadResponse>
        <house>The White House</house>
        <has-large-house>true</has-large-house>
        <completed-houses>1600 Pennsylvania Ave.</completed-houses> 
    </PayloadResponse>

JSON={"house":"The White House",
      "completedHouses":"1600 Pennsylvania Ave.",
      "has-large-house":true}
```